# Foreach Counter Based on Value of Field

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have a bit of code that lists homes, and the number of beds each home has.  I would like to use a foreach loop with a counter, so when the bed count changes I can echo the end of the table, and the beginning of a new table (so as to separate the homes for sale by the number of bedrooms).  Here is what I have now;

```
foreach ($unitsForSaleData as $row) {
if($units_for_sale['beds'] == 0){
    echo '<h1> Studios For Sale </h1>';
    echo $tableTop;

} else {
    echo $tableBottom;
    echo '<h1>'.$units_for_sale['beds'].' Bedroom Condos For Sale </h1>';
    echo $tableTop;
}

$contentHere
}
```

This code produces a new table for every line though, so it's no good.  Anyway to do this?  I only want the table header echoed when the $units_for_sale['beds'] changes.

Comment: you are going to end up with duplicate sections,  for example lets say your results in bed count are 1,1,4,1,5,6,7.  you will end up with 2 sections with 1 bed.

Comment: The beds are ordered, and it goes like 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7.

Comment: Barmar's solution is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No counter needed, just use a variable to keep track of the last one displayed.

```
$last_bed = null;

foreach (...) {
    if($units_for_sale['beds'] == 0){
        echo '<h1> Studios For Sale </h1>';
        echo $tableTop;

    } else {
        if ($units_for_sale['beds'] !== $last_bed) {
            if ($last_bed !== null) { // End previous table
                echo $tableBottom;
            }
            echo '<h1>'.$units_for_sale['beds'].' Bedroom Condos For Sale </h1>';
            echo $tableTop; // Start new table
            $last_bed = $units_for_sale['beds'];
        }
    }
    ... // Display row data here
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still puts only one <tr> in each <table>. Does it make a difference that this is a foreach loop and not while?

Comment: `<tr>` and `<td>` shouldn't be part of `$tableBottom` and `$tableTop`, they need to be printed for each item. I've updated my answer.

Comment: You seem to be trying to put `<h1>` elements directly in the table, without wrapping them in `<tr>` and `<td>` or `<th>`. All table elements have to be in these elements.

Comment: No the idea was to close the table ($tableBottom) and then echo the H1.  I just tried your refreshed code, but without the <tr><td> in the echo tags and it works, except that it echos the title as many times as there are in the table.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I keep reading bottom and top backwards.

Comment: It sure would help if you indented your code so the structure is readable.

Comment: I misunderstood what this value was, now I understand. I've moved the `<h1>` inside the `if`, that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$beds = 0;

echo '<h1> Studios For Sale </h1>';

while(notendofloop) // foreach ($array as $val)
{
  if($beds != $units_for_sale['beds']){
    if ($beds != 0) echo $tableBottom;

    echo $tableTop;
    $beds = $units_for_sale['beds'];
  }

  echo '<h1>'.$units_for_sale['beds'].' Bedroom Condos For Sale </h1>';
}
```

You have not provided the full loop so use the existing loop details.  The essential thing is to init a variable `$beds` before the loop and check for it's value within it to determine when to output the table.

Comment: Would this also work with a foreach loop?  How would that be coded?

Comment: @GregL Yes this would work for foreach loops or any other kind of loop.  As I said in the answer, the key is the initialising of a variable outside the loop and check for its value/increment it within.  If you copy the core of my loop to yours it should work allowing for any typos.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can do. In a foreach you can add a "count" value in your loop declaration. Here is the code that would suit your requirements:

```
foreach($units as $key=>$units_for_sale){
    if($units_for_sale['beds']!=0){
        echo '<h1>'.$units_for_sale['beds'].' Bedroom Condos For Sale </h1>';
        echo ($key+1!=count($array)?$tableBottom.$tableTop:$tableBottom;
    }else{
         echo '<h1> Studios For Sale </h1>';
         echo $tableTop;
    }
}
```